# Assigning users to tasks in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops

I've just joined my friend's Team Services account (free for the first 5 users account). If I visit the home page (https://XXXXXXX.visualstudio.com/Development/Development%20Team), I can see us both listed as Team Members. I can create backlog items/tasks and assign them to myself. My friend can create backlog items/tasks and assign them to himself. However, we can't assign each other.

Why could this be and any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In the Assign To dropdown list of a work item, it shows a list of most recently used users.

Because you have just joined VSTS and never assigned work items to others, you could only see yourself in the dropdown list. To assign your work item to your friends, you could search his username at Assign To textbox.

Comment: That's right, thanks! Just click on the "Unassigned" text and click and search your friends.

Comment: What an awful UX. Hope they change this.

Comment: Note that to search, you have to begin typing and then click the search item inside the dropdown. Awful UX indeed.

Comment: I would never have thought of this.I was searching for 15 minutes to figure out how to add the newly added user to my work item.

Answer (score 12):

In VSTS, if you do not see the user in the AssignTo drop down list to assign a user to a project Task, you just need to take a few more steps.

1. I don't see the user I want to assign the task to, in the assign to dropdown.  I only see myself
   [image]
2. all you need to do, is type a few letters of the person you want to assign the task to, in the dropdown box.  You will see a little search magnifying glass
   [image]
3. if you click the search magnifying glass, you will see the list of users in your VSTS domain.
   [image]