# How to Assign task in VSTS Online

Tags: azure-devops

I have created my account in Visual Studio Team Services, and added the team members as well.  I am able to see the uses got added.

But I cannot see them when I tried to assign work for them. Everybody's acccess level including me, is Basic and I have added them as Project Contributors, and me in Project Administrators group.

When I tried to create a new work item (new feature), on the Unassigned text box, no users name is popping up.

Any idea where I am going wrong? Please provide any suggestion.

Comment: check this if helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668109/assigning-users-to-tasks-in-visual-studio-team-services

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning users to tasks in Visual Studio Team Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668109/assigning-users-to-tasks-in-visual-studio-team-services)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work item control is changed to a MRU control, so people you care about most show up immediately. Since you never assign tasks before, you would see "No identities found" in the drop down:

[image]

You can type the user name and then click "Search" in the drop down:

[image]

Then you'll see the user:

[image]