# Why can't I assign work items to a team member?

Tags: azure-devops

In my organisation, I have tried setting up my team member as having Basic Access and Stakeholder access.
However neither allow me to assign a work item to her.

She uses an gmail address to log in.

In my organisation->Users->User I make her a project administrator but it reverts to Custom.

In my project->Teams-> MyTeam
I can see we are both members

However when I go to assign a work item there is only 1 person in the combo box.

How do I enable the ability to assign work items to her?

[Update]

I think a Microsoft Account or AD login is needed
[looking at this quick start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/create-organization?view=vsts)

However if gmail accounts don't work then we should be prevented from adding them as users.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?toc=%2fazure%2fdevops%2fbilling%2ftoc.json&%3bbc=%2fazure%2fdevops%2fbilling%2fbreadcrumb%2ftoc.json&%3bview=vsts&view=vsts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668109/assigning-users-to-tasks-in-visual-studio-team-services?rq=1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

because I did not realize that I need to type part of the users name and click search.
I was mislead by the combo box with just my name in it.

Comment: I just had the same problem.  Seems unintuitive, at least for small teams where you would expect each user could easily fit in a combo box.

Comment: It is pathetic how common this issue seems to be ... I'm finding this thread 4 years later as well!

Comment: That was not super intuitive. Thanks for sharing this solution!

Answer (score 1):

When you invite a user, you are only inviting an email address and that could be Gmail, Apple, or Amazon. When they select the invitation link, they are taken to the experience where they are asked to sign in with their Microsoft account (MSA).

Comment: That makes sense. We will test it.

Comment: ah maybe she had access all along. I was just confused because she is team member 2 of 2 and she does not show in the combo box!