# Can't @mention or Assign Work Items to Other Users in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

In the Azure DevOps project I'm currently working on, I am unable to use the @ mention feature and am not able to assign work items to other users because no users are ever found.   I am aware that you [should be able to search for other users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49576434/4297541) if they don't initially show-up in the drop-down list, but searching *always* returns "No identities found".

Other members of my team that have elevated permissions than I do *can* use these features because they *are* able to search for any other user in the same Azure DevOps project.   My project administrator gave-up trying to figure-out why these features won't work for me.

Is there a setting in the Azure DevOps Project Settings Permissions that enables or disables the ability to view other user names?

Here is an example of me trying to look-up my own name to assign a bug to myself without success:

[image]

And here is an example of me trying to @mention a user in a bug discussion section without success:

[image]

*** Update ***
When my project administrator gives me project administrator rights, I am able to @mention others.  Obviously, that isn't the desired user level for a non admin like myself.

Comment: You can input the full email address in the "Assigned To" field and check if the issue still occur. For your first attachemnt, the error message shows that 'kcz' is your first type and it is an unknown identity.Did the 'kcz**' is your account name? For your second attachment, it seems like the user name is Ben Fox, but in you @mention the user as '@fox', are there uesrs who start with fox? If you type "@Ben", will the issue still occur?

Comment: @Frank Wang-MSFT  "kcz" are the first 3 letters of my co-worker's last name from a previous attempt to look-up a user.  "tay" are the first 3 letters of my last name.  I've tried inserting known email addresses into the search and still get the "No identities found" response.  "@Ben" also returns "No identities found".

Comment: Please try if you can use the REST API to update the "Assigned To" field in an existed work item. If not, please share the error message. Here is the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#uri-parameters

Comment: @Frank Wang-MSFT Thanks for the link.  I'll admit that I'm stuck trying to figure-out how to get the OAuth2 token via PostMan (or some other tool) based on the provided documentation :-/

Comment: You can use personal access token instead of getting the OAuth2 token via PostMan. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops

Comment: @FrankWang-MSFT Thanks, the PAT makes things a lot easier.   Here's the response I got when trying to assign a work item that was assigned to me to my co-worker (who's name has been removed from the response):

```
"innerException": null,
    "message": "The identity value '{Employee Name}' for field 'Assigned To' is an unknown identity.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.WorkItemFieldInvalidException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server",
    "typeKey": "WorkItemFieldInvalidException",
    "errorCode": 600171,
    "eventId": 3200
```

Comment: When my project administrator gives me project administrator rights, I am able to @mention others, but that's obviously not the right permission level for someone like myself that is just a user who needs to work with work items.

Comment: What Security group were you added to, initially? And what level of access do you wish to have?

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT I originally had contributor rights.  What is also odd is that even though I was granted project administrator rights (which I still have), my ability to look-up users has gone away?!?!  I have no idea why it would work for a few minutes and then stop working.

Comment: @PoorInRichfield It seems that there is a problem with your account. To resolve your issue, I would like suggest you report this issue on Developer Community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html which is our main forum for product issues. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: @FrankWang-MSFT Thank you.  I've opened a new thread in the forums at the following URL:  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/790641/cant-2.html